# This moderator keeps picking up on me 4 no eligible reason, Why?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question,

> Is there any way to get all documents for a user in SharePoint online
>   enterprise, if not personal ?

In easy English it means I would prioritize a answer which will work on both personal and enterprise. Some guy answers the question that is suitable for enterprise office 365. Then I comment this,

> i had this in my mind but my manager is planning to get everyone in
>   company office 365 personal where there is no search api. but thank
>   you

Which means - your answer is right for enterprise version, but I will wait for a day or 2 as if someone answers me for personal office 365 too. if no one answers then I will mark your answer correct as i will assume there is no way in personal office 365.

I Cannot think why moderator needed to comment this,

> @CustomizedName, you say in your question that you are using
>   SharePoint Online Enterprise, and at the same time claims there is no
>   search API. Getting me confused! –  Robert Lindgren♦ 23 mins ago

Does moderator has any problem with understanding simple English or is he just keep picking up on me again and again and again ?

[How to get all documents in SharePoint Online for a user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/how-to-get-all-documents-in-sharepoint-online-for-a-user)

Comment: He's not picking on you. He's just trying to inform you that you will get better answer if your question is more specific. That's his task.

Comment: @BennySkogberg My question was specific and his comments were not helpful.

Comment: @CustomizedName, I still think that comment was very useful. It's purpose was for you to rewise your question to make it more comprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

Yep of  course we do not understand English, and surely we like to track down individual users and give them a hard time... Do you really feel that is the case?

Because:

No we do not, what would anyone earn by doing that? We want this community to blossom and to be a place where both the "new kids on the block" and the "old foxes" wants to hang out!

Regarding that specific comment, I felt your question was not very clearly composed (I still do, it lacks information and details). A respected user took from his time to answer it anyway.

He gets a comment from you, indicating he has not answered what you have asked, and gets no upvote from you.

Since I read the question in a way where his answer would be very valid, and at least deserve an upvote, I wrote you a comment on that.

Getting answers you feel is wrong is usually a quite good indication that you should clarify your question and / or your mission.

I see nothing in my comment that should trigger this reaction. Feel free to point it out to me :)

I can also not see why you feel that I "keep picking on you", afaik we have had very little interaction, and I have even helped answer at least one if your questions in the past.

Apologizes if you feel "picked on", that is never the goal! The goal is to help you get your questions answered, in a way that will help not only you, but also future readers, now and in the future!

Happy Easter!

Comment: C'mon, Robert - at least give the guy some ointment for that burn...

Comment: "Because:
No we do not, what would anyone earn by doing that? We want this community to blossom and to be a place where both the "new kids on the block" and the "old foxes" wants to hang out!" 

I was talking about you, not all moderators, maybe you need to understand question properly more then me specifying what I need to ask in my questions ;) !!

Comment: Also you cannot force me to vote someone regardless of how good or bad their answer is Full Stop !!

Comment: @CustomizedName, please just stop. No one is picking on you, and you are very welcome to be part of this community (playing by its rules, and keeping a good and polite tone)

Comment: I just replied to your answer; bye; thank you;